# How to change the background color of the Settings page and not the Editor?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How do I change the background color of the Settings page, not the Editor, but the Settings page? I know it probably involves changing a `workbench.colorCustomization` token, but I don't know which one it is or if it even exists. Also, is there some sort of extension that allows you to inspect the UI elements/icons of VS Code?

I have already tried changing the `editor.background` token, which applied to not just the Editor, but also the Welcome and Settings pages. I was able to change the background color for the Welcome page using the `welcomePage.background` token, but I don't know how to change it for Settings.

I want the Settings background color to change so I can see it better.

Comment: @starball It's the same issue it seems (if I recall when I made the question), but definitely doesn't really solve it. I think VSCode doesn't have a specific color option for the backgrounds of other windows, so it just uses editor.background. Would be nice if they had different background color options per window.

Comment: @starball Is there a way I can close it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like you can.  If under `workbench.colorCustomizations` you type `settings` you will get the list of available `settings` page items of which you can change the color.

Perhaps one or more of the `foreground` colors to change the text color will help you.

The [Custom CSS and JS Loader](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=be5invis.vscode-custom-css#overview) may allow you to change the color of the settings page.  You can inspect vscode's elements by `Help/Toggle Developer Tools` to find out what element you need to target with that extension.

`<div class="settings-editor   "` or a child of that.  Set its background-color to what you want using that extension.

Comment: Alright, I guess I can't change the background of the Settings page (probably because it shares the same token as `editor.background`) and I don't know how to use that CSS and JS extension nor do I know CSS. So I guess just changing the foreground colors will have to do.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no specific customization for the settings window background. They are all considered as an "editor" and are all affected by the same setting:

```
    "editor.background": "#282a36",
```

The only [colors related to the settings window](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color#settings-editor-colors) are these:

```
    "settings.checkboxBackground": "#ffb86c",
    "settings.checkboxBorder": "#191a21",
    "settings.checkboxForeground": "#f6f6f4",
    "settings.dropdownBackground": "#262626",
    "settings.dropdownBorder": "#191a21",
    "settings.dropdownForeground": "#f6f6f4",
    "settings.headerForeground": "#f6f6f4",
    "settings.modifiedItemIndicator": "#ffb86c",
    "settings.numberInputBackground": "#262626",
    "settings.numberInputBorder": "#191a21",
    "settings.numberInputForeground": "#f6f6f4",
    "settings.textInputBackground": "#262626",
    "settings.textInputBorder": "#191a21",
    "settings.textInputForeground": "#f6f6f4",
```